# 500 - Internal Server Error with extra pair of brackets

Tags: php, internal-server-error, brackets

I have been looking for an error in my code since an hour. This was the error:

Writing:

```
if(isset(($_POST['to'])))
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['to']))
```

I don't get why is this extra pair of brackets causing an Internal Server Error.

I don't think putting brackets around a variable never changes its value. I mean,

```
$a = $b;
$c = ($b);

$a==$c; //True
```

I am curious as to know why is it an error?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

The above error was occurring for normal variable also.

Comment: @Jack there are 3 opening and 3 closing parenthesis

Comment: isset is a php function.http://in2.php.net/isset

Comment: @ghost I know that. Thats why I tagged `php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) is not a function but a language construct; as such, its definition can be found in the [language parser](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L1258).

```
T_ISSET '(' isset_variables ')' { $$ = $3; }
```

It only expects one pair of braces; passing another pair will cause a parse error.

Comment: If it is a parse error, why didn't it show up even after enabling all the errors?

Comment: @nitish712, it will 100% cause a parse error if you have error reporting on correctly. The reason you got a 500 was because your configuration didnt want to show the PHP error.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that isset can not take a function in parameter. You have to pass it a value. Your extra pair of parenthesis may be evaluated as a 'function' or something that need to be evaluated.

Normally, when you try to pass a function to isset, you get this error :

```
Can't use method return value in write context
```

Answer (score 1):

[isset](https://www.php.net/isset):

**Warning**

> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

Answer (score 0):

Information can be passed to functions through arguments. An argument is just like a variable.

Arguments are specified after the function name, inside the parentheses. You can add as many arguments as you want, just seperate them with a comma.

The following example has a function with one argument ($fname). When the familyName() function is called, we also pass along a name (e.g. Jani), and the name is used inside the function, which outputs several different first names, but an equal last name:

```
<?php
function familyName($fname)
{
echo "$fname Refsnes.<br>";
}

familyName("Jani");
familyName("Hege");
familyName("Stale");
familyName("Kai Jim");
familyName("Borge");
?>
```